Prove $2^x > x^3$, where $x \geq 10$ (specifically with calculus)
Besides the inductive proof for this, I'm not understanding how to prove this with calculus.
I understand when $x = 10$, $(2^x = 1024) > (x^3 = 1000)$. I tried to then further show that the derivative of $f(x) = 2^x - x^3$ which is $2^x\ln2 - 3x^2 > 0$, where $x \geq 10$ (based on technique from How would you prove $\log_{2}x < \sqrt x$ for $x > 16$?). I can see the derivative $> 0$ for x = 10, but I'm not sure how exactly to manipulate the inequality to show it's also true for x > 10 (it's intuitive/obvious, but proving it is confusing me here).
Kindly let me know.

This probably isn't the standard proof, but letting f = 2^x, g = x^3...
Given (at x = 10, f > g) and (at x > 10, the derivative of f is greater than the derivative of g), f > g is "obvious".
The latter (2^x ln(2) > 3x^2) can be shown by doing the same thing, taking the derivative, and obviously an exponential is greater than the linear for x > 10.

Hint: It's equivalent to show $x \ln 2 > 3 \ln x$, or $\frac{\ln x}{x} < \frac{\ln 2}{3}$.  That suggests using calculus to study properties of the function $f(x) := \frac{\ln x}{x}$.

Do you have the mean value theorem available to you?

@preferred_anon Forgot about it lol :) Kindly if you could elaborate via an answer I'd be grateful

You can solve the equality using Lambert function. This would give $x=9.93954$. Then $\cdots\cdots$

You have correctly stated that to prove $f(x) := 2^x - x^3 > 0$ for $x \geq 10$, it is sufficient to prove that

$f(10) > 0$, and
$f'(x) = 2^x \ln 2 - 3x^2 > 0$ for all $x \geq 10$.

To prove the second point, notice that it's very similar to your original problem! The difference is, instead of proving $\color{red}{2^x - x^3 > 0}$ for all $x \geq 10$, you want to prove that $\color{red}{2^x \ln 2 - 3x^2 > 0}$ for all $x \geq 10$. The only difference is the inequality.
Perhaps, you can repeat what you did earlier?
Let's define $g(x) := 2^x \ln 2 - 3x^2$. To prove that $g(x) > 0$ for $x \geq 10$, it is sufficient to prove that

$g(10) > 0$, and
$g'(x) = 2^x (\ln 2)^2 - 6x > 0$ for all $x \geq 10$.

Proving $g(10) > 0$ is trickier than proving $f(10) > 0$, but it's relatively straightforward. (Try it yourself! You want to show that $1024 \ln 2 - 300 > 0$. Can you show that $\ln 2 > 300/1024$?)
As for proving $g'(x) > 0$, well...
To prove the second point, notice that it's very similar to your original problem! The difference is, instead of proving $\color{red}{2^x - x^3 > 0}$ for all $x \geq 10$, you want to prove that $\color{red}{2^x (\ln 2)^2 - 6x > 0}$ for all $x \geq 10$. The only difference is the inequality.
Perhaps, you can repeat what you did earlier?

PS. This is just one way to solve this inequality. This method may not work for other inequalities. For example, say you want to prove $h(x) := x^2 + 1 > 0$ for all $x \geq -5$. Unfortunately,

$h(-5) = 26 > 0$, but
$h'(x) = 2x$ which is negative when $-5 \leq x < 0$.


Cool! Since $2^x(\ln2)^3 - 6 = f^{'''}(x)$ and it's easy to show $f^{'''}(10) > 0$, then showing  $f^{'''}(x) > 0,  \forall x \geq 10$ is also easy since $f^{'''}(x) \geq 1024(\ln2)^3 - 6 > 0$

Does this sort of recursive method always work or is this just unique for problems like this (and if so how?) ?

It doesn't always work. In this case there is a polynomial which degree decreases with each iteration, and the successive derivatives of $2^x$ are very simple. For many other functions, the derivatives are increasingly complex.

@jjagmath what are some calculus strategies to keep in mind when trying to prove a function >=0 past a certain input?

@VTand what are some calculus strategies to keep in mind when trying to prove a function >=0 past a certain input?

@BobMarley Sometimes it helps to find stationary points, i.e., values of $x$ such that $f'(x) = 0$. For example, the problem is solved if you can prove that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all local minimums and boundary values $x$. Maybe the fact that composition of increasing functions is also increasing can help you too.

@VTand Tysm! Btw when you said show ln 2 > 300/1024, was your reasoning also that ln 2 > 1/2 b/c $(\ln \sqrt e = \frac{1}{2}) < (\ln \sqrt 4 = \ln 2)$

@Bob Marley Yes, that's my line of thought.

To show $2^x > x^3$ when $x\geq10$ taking the logarithm shows it is enough to show $x\ln(2) > 3 \ln(x)$ when $x\geq10.$
It is sufficient to show $g(x) = x\ln(2)-3\ln(x)> 0$ when $x\geq10.$
Now $g'(x)=\ln(2)-\tfrac{3}{x}\geq \ln(2)-\tfrac{3}{10}>.69-.3>0$ when $x\geq10.$ So $g(x)$ is increasing when $x\geq10$ and $g(10)=10\ln(2)-3\ln(10)>10\times 0.6931 - 3\times 2.3026 = 6.931 - 6.9026>0.$ Consequently, $g(x)\geq g(10)>0$ when $x\geq10$ as we needed to show.

Let $g(x)=\frac{2^x}{x^3}$. Then $$g'(x)=\frac{\ln2x^32^x-3x^22^x}{x^6}>0$$
gives $x>\frac{3}{\ln2}$ for which $g(x)$ is increasing function. Now, $g(10)>1$ and $10>\frac3{\ln2}$. So, $g(x)>1$ for $x>10$.

Your solution is the simplest one (+)

Say $f(x) = 2^x$ and $g(x) = x^3$.

Hopefully you are satisfied that it is enough to prove that $f'(x) > g'(x)$ for all $x>10$ (hint: integrate both sides). But that inequality is not obvious to me.
In fact, since $f'(10) > g'(10)$ (obvious from what you have already, since $\ln(2) > \tfrac{3}{10}$), we could apply the same argument, and it would be enough even to prove that $f''(x) > g''(x)$ for all $x>10$.
You see where I'm going... $f''(10) > g''(10)$ (since $\ln(2) > \tfrac{2}{10}$), so we just need to show $f'''(x) > g'''(x)$.
But $g'''(x) = 6$, and $f'''(x) = \ln(2)^{3} 2^{x}$, which is certainly bigger than (say) 100 for $x>10$. So we're done.


Consider $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Easy to show that $f$ is strictly decreasing for $x>e$.
Now, we have since $2^{10}>10^3$ that $2^{\frac{1}{3}}>10^{\frac{1}{10}}$
Since $f$ is decreasing for $x>e$, we have for $x>10$, $10^{\frac{1}{10}}>x^{\frac{1}{x}}$
So that $2^{\frac{1}{3}}>x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x>10$
